# Laravel 5.2 authorization form POST

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel in general and working with version 5.2. Basically I needed to add 2 fields to my users table. Opposed to `name` I have `first_name` and `last_name`. I dont want to use the auth views set up in Laravel so I am just looking where to POST my user login form to.

I found some stuff from 5.1 that said to `method="POST" action="/auth/login"` and have the route `Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');` but that part of the controller seems to be gone.

I see the validator and create functions (which I used to create the user doing a POST to the Create method)

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'last_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

You think there would be an easy way to run this form in 5.2 like there was in 5.1

Answer (score 0):

I am going to leave the question but I ended up doing a POST to a method inside a controller and adding this

```
use Auth; //add to top of controller 

//inside the class
public function authenticate()
    {
        $email      = ($_POST["email"]);
        $password   = ($_POST["password"]);

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
```